# Is $x_n(t) = t^n$ for $n\ge 1$ dense in $L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

My question concerns the following problem

> Let $x_n(t) = t^n$ for $n\ge 1$. Is $\mathrm{span}(x_n; n\ge 1)$ dense in $L^1([0,1])$?

By Weierstrass' approximation theorem, it suffices to check whether the constant function $1$ is contained in the $L^1$-closure of the linear span of the $x_n$.

I think this is not the case, but I haven't found a proof so far.

*Some simple observations:* I know that if $1$ is contained in the $L^1$-closure, then we can find a sequence of polynomials $p_n\in \mathrm{span}(x_n; n\ge 1)$ such that $p_n\to 1$ in $L^1$, almost everywhere and almost uniformly. Furthermore the sequence $q_n(x) = \int_0^x p_n(t) \, dt$ will converge uniformly to $x$ on $[0,1]$.

I don't see how this helps, though.

Comment: We certainly have $x^{1/n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$ in $L^1[0,1]$ (monotone convergence), so it suffices to approximate the $n$-th root functions arbitrarily well by a polynomial. I didn't verify it in detail, but a sufficiently high Taylor expansion of $x^{1/n}$ around $1$ should do the job uniformly on $[\varepsilon,1]$ for each $n$ with an error controllable in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $n$.

Comment: @t.b.: Interesting idea. Thanks! I don't know whether this works via Taylor-approximation, but it certainly does by considering the corresponding Bernstein polynomials $$B_m(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^{1/n} x^k(1-x)^{m-k}$$ since the constant term with $k=0$ vanishes. Nice! =)

Comment: Heh :) I noticed that there is some work left to do with the Taylor approximation idea because the constant won't vanish. Nice idea to work with Bernstein polynomials!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a write up of the solution based on t.b.'s nice idea in the comments:

> **Claim:** Let $x_n(t) = t^n$. Then $\mathrm{span}(x_n; n\ge 1)$ is dense as a subspace of $L^1([0,1])$.

**Proof:** By monotone convergence, the sequence $x^{1/m}$ converges to $1$ in $L^1([0,1])$. It therefore suffices to check that $x^{1/m} \in \overline{\mathrm{span}(x_n; n\ge 1)}$ for all $m\in \mathbb N$.

The latter follows from the fact that the sequence of Bernstein polynomials

$$B_k(x) =  \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki \left(\frac{i}{k}\right)^{1/m}x^i (1-x)^{k-i}$$

converges to $x^{1/m}$ uniformly and is contained in $\mathrm{span}(x_n; n\ge 1)$ (the constant term where $i=0$ vanishes). $\square$

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any finite collection of  terms from the series of monomials $(t^n)$ ($n=0,1,2,3,\dots$) and the resulting linear span is still dense in $C([0,1]$ (and so in the corresponding $L^1$-space).  This is a consequence of a  deep result---the theorem of Muentz---one of the  central results of approximation theory.  You can easily find information and the precise formulation (which allows one to remove suitable infinite sets of indices) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Sounds very interesting!

Comment: @jbc: I think you are misremembering the theorem of Muentz. To achieve densitiy in $C[0,1]$, we always need to have the monomial $1$, since any polynomial in the span of $(t^n)_{n>0}$ satisfies $p(0) = 0$. (It seems like one can remove higher monomials in the way you describe, though).

Comment: @SamL.  Sorry, you are right, of coure. To remove the constant functions in the $L^1$-case, you need an additional argument (truncate the function to be approximated near $0$ and extrapolate linearly to the origin.  Now use the version  for continuous functions that vanish at zero).  Thanks again.

Comment: As a further ccomment there are versions of Muentz which apply directly to $L^1$-spaces---see, e.g., the book on polynomials by Borwein et al.  This spares one the necessity of the tweaking argument above.

Comment: @jbc: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Approximating $1$ by polynomials without constant term is essentially the same as approximating $1/x$ by arbitrary polynomials.

Of course there is a twist in that $1/x$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$, but take $P(x)$ to approximate $\min\{1/x,M\}$ for some large $M$ to within $\epsilon$ (in sup norm).

Then $|xP(x)-1| < \epsilon$ for all $x > 1/M$, and for $x < 1/M$ we have $0 < P(x) < 2M$ (assuming $\epsilon$ is reasonable) so $|xP(x)-1| \le 1$.  The $L^1$ difference is bounded by $\epsilon + 1/M$, which we can send to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea to consider $1/x$ and the usual monomial basis, instead!